# Python: Manipulating date and time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

In my example below, I want to group the bookings by month and year.
There are Two things I want to manipulate:
1. When I print the variable: rawpm, I only want to display the month and the year
2. When I print the variable: rawpj, I only want to display the year.

My example .csv file:

```
Bookingsnumber;Saleprice;Area;Place;Purchase;Bookingsdate
C12015024;1000;Wildkogel Ski Arena;Bramberg am Wildkogel;800;1-1-2019
C12015250;1000;Les Quatre Vallées;La Tzoumaz;800;3-3-2019
C12025062;1000;Les Quatre Vallées;La Tzoumaz;800;7-1-2020
C12025085;1000;Paradiski - Les Arcs;Vallandry;800;9-1-2020
C12025085;1000;Paradiski - Les Arcs;Vallandry;800;9-3-2020
C12025085;1000;Paradiski - Les Arcs;Vallandry;800;12-3-2020
```

My example code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel (r'example.csv', parse_dates =["Bookingsdate"], index_col ="Bookingsdate", format='%Y')

#Revenue all websites per year
    rawpj = df.Saleprice.resample('Y').sum()
    print(rawpj)

    ndf = pd.read_excel (r'example.csv', parse_dates =["Bookingsdate"], index_col ="Bookingsdate", format='%m/%Y)

    #Revenue all website per month
    rawpm = ndf.Saleprice.resample('M').sum()
    print(rawpm)
```

Desired result:

```
Bookingsdate
2019    2000
2020    4000
Freq: A-DEC, Name: Saleprice, dtype: int64
Bookingsdate
2019-01    1000
2019-02       0
2019-03    1000
2019-04       0
2019-05       0
2019-06       0
2019-07       0
2019-08       0
2019-09       0
2019-10       0
2019-11       0
2019-12       0
2020-01    2000
2020-02       0
2020-03    2000
Freq: M, Name: Saleprice, dtype: int64
```

Thanks in advance,
Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df = pd.read_excel (r'example.csv')

df['Bookingsdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Bookingsdate'],format='%d/%m/%Y')

#Revenue per Year
df['year'] = df['Bookingsdate'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y'))
grouped_df = df.groupby('year').sum()
print(grouped_df)
```

And:

```
ndf = pd.read_excel (r'example.csv')

ndf['Bookingsdate'] = pd.to_datetime(ndf['Bookingsdate'])

#Revenue per Year/Month
ndf['ym'] = ndf['Bookingsdate'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%Y'))
grouped_ndf = ndf.groupby('ym').sum()
print(grouped_ndf)
```